# Smtlib trouble with the code

Tags: z3, smt

I have this following code

```
(set-logic QF_LIA)
(declare-fun w () Int)
(declare-fun x () Int)
(declare-fun y () Int)
(declare-fun z () Int)
(assert (> x y))
(assert (> y z))
(push 1)
(assert (> z x))
(check-sat) ; unsat
(get-info :statistics)
(pop 1)
(push 1)
(check-sat (= x w)) ; sat
```

The code should return unsat on first (check-sat) and sat on second (check-sat), but I get unknown.

Can someone please tell me what's the problem. I am using windows 7, jSMTLIB using cygwin

Thanks
Saif

Answer (score 3):

I don't know which backend in jSMTLIB you used for solving this. However, `(check-sat (= x w))` is not even legal in SMT-LIB v2.

When I change that line to:

```
(assert (= x w))
(check-sat)
```

I get `unsat` and `sat` from Z3 web interface, which is of our expectation.

Note that `(get-info :statistics)` is also incorrect; the correct option is `(get-info :all-statistics)`. You can read more about SMT-LIB v2 standard in [their documentation](http://goedel.cs.uiowa.edu/smtlib/docs.html).